# Running xctool run-tests without building tests on machine

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xctool

I would like to run my tests using xctool without having to build the tests on the machine prior.  Basically, I want to build the tests on one machine, transfer them to several other machines and run them in parallel from there.

So I need to know what files the command 
`xctool run-tests` requires in order to run the tests, so I can transfer those files to each computer in order to parallelize my runs.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the file produced by `xctool build-tests`, which builds the tests but does not run them.

The last file output by `xctool` on the command-line is the path the final `.xctest` – or at least it is for me. Either way, that's what you need.

https://github.com/facebook/xctool#building-tests

If you just want to execute that test bundle, you can do something like this:

```
xcrun -sdk iphonesimulator simctl spawn booted $(xcrun --show-sdk-platform-path -sdk iphonesimulator)/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/xctest /path/to/tests.xctest
```